# How to create multiple users in Documentum

Tags: java, documentum6.5, dfc

Is there any way to create 30+ user with same groups and ACL name in one shot?

I have tried using DQL and make script, but even that doesn't run in one shot in Documentum DQL editor.

Does anyone has any simpler way to create users in Documentum aplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use java to loop over some dfc code like this :

```
        IDfUser dfcUser = (IDfUser) getSession().newObject("dm_user");
        dfcUser.setUserName("username");
        dfcUser.setUserLoginName("username");

        dfcUser.setString("user_source","inline password");
        dfcUser.setString("user_password","somepassword");
        dfcUser.setString("user_os_name","username");
        dfcUser.setString("description","new user description");
```

also, you could use a tool like Qit : [Qit by Qtree](http://www.qtree.be/qit)

You can develop your own plugins, I am currently developing one to duplicate a user.
These plugins will appear on the website soon.

Comment: My Idea is to read the username and data from any XLS sheet and create them auromaticatly

Answer (score 0):

IDQL (idql32.exe) tool which is installed on the Content Server bin folder can execute a file full of DQL commands. Use the GO command to seperate each DQL